# Is it possible to apply an immutability policy to an Azure Blob block?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

It seems possible for Container and Account level but I don't find any reference [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage) to do it for a specific blob block in the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can lease blob for infinite so it will be immutable for write and delete operation-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob

Comment: This isn't the same as WORM policies for immutable storage (and doesn't apply for compliance purposes), and requires an extra step for every object written.

Comment: I read somewhere in the official documentation leases are recommended only for short periods of time (they were designed as a synchronization mechanism). I would prefer WORM policies if they can be applied individually